# MaterialCalendar with AppCompat Theme

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme

I have Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar as the primary app theme and want to use the MaterialCalendar widget.

At first there was this error

```
com.google.android.material.datepicker.MaterialDatePicker requires a value for the
attr/materialCalendarFullscreenTheme attribute to be set in your app theme.
You can either set the attribute in your theme or update your theme to inherit from 
Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
```

After adding `<item name="materialCalendarFullscreenTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Fullscreen</item>` got this error

```
com.google.android.material.datepicker.MaterialDatePicker requires a value for the 
attr/colorSurface attribute to be set in your app theme.
You can either set the attribute in your theme or update your theme to inherit from 
Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
```

After adding `<item name="colorSurface">@color/colorPrimary</item>` got this error

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25 in mtrl_picker_fullscreen:
Binary XML file line #48 in mtrl_picker_header_fullscreen: Error inflating class
com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
```

How to make the widget work with the AppCompat them?

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution for this issue ?

Comment: No. I gave up and switched to `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar`